# How to write some Lua tables in one JSON-field?

Tags: arrays, json, lua

I have main Lua-table which contains some subtables, for example:

```
p = { {1,2}, {3,4}}
```

I need to go through these tables and write the result to the JSON-file as follows:

```
    {
      "numbers":[
{
        "my" :[
        { "n1" = 1,
          "n2" = 2
        },
        { "n1" = 3,
          "n2" = 4
        }
    ]
}
]
}
```

My code(doesn't work) :

```
json = require('json')
local res = {}
local p = { {1,2}, {3,4} }
for i = 1, #p do
  table.insert(res, { my = {
    n1 = p[i][1],
    n2 = p[i][2]
}})
end
json.encode({numbers = res})
```

At the exit, I have about the following :

```
    {
      "numbers":[
     {
      "my":{
        { "n1" = 1,
          "n2" = 2
        }
    },
      "my":{
        { "n1" = 3,
          "n2" = 4
        }
    }
}
]
    }
```

Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

```
local res = {my = {}}
local p = { {1,2}, {3,4} }
for i = 1, #p do
   table.insert(res.my, {
      n1 = p[i][1],
      n2 = p[i][2]
   })
end
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21299587)

Comment: @Nick - Could you please elaborate what "some explaining words" should be about?  What is unclear in my answer (in the context of the question)?

Comment: Something along the lines of how does it solve the problem? What was wrong with OPs code and how does this fix that?

Comment: @Nick - My answer differs from OP's code just in two lines.  Assuming you've read and understand the question, it's pretty obvious how this solution solves the problem.  If you (or someone else) don't understand - please ask particular question (so that I could grasp what exactly is unclear).  Your phrase "Raw code snippets are not very helpful" is not very helpful (and is incorrect, IMO).  BTW, the link you gave said: "Brevity is acceptable".  So, why did you mark my answer as "recommended for deletion"?